# WPF MVVM: How do I asynchronously load data from a complex ViewModel, with child ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been trying to find a good pattern for loading data in complex ViewModels. I have done a lot of reading online, and a lot of experimenting, but I am still very new to asynchronous operations.

I have read the [articles written by Stephen Cleary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding), and I see how this works. I like the pattern of designing your view to handle different states (busy, faulted, loaded). A class like `NotifyTask` looks excellent to use for binding to a property that is loaded asynchronously.

I am having some trouble conceptualizing how this scales to a more complicated use case. Lets assume a ViewModel with multiple properties. Some properties are simple, and can be loaded synchronously. Some properties require a trip to a datastore to retrieve their value. Some properties are collections of child ViewModels that themselves have various properties requiring either synchronous or asynchronous loading.

At first, I felt like the cleanest approach would be to wrap all of the data loading for the entire ViewModel graph into one asynchronous loading operation. This would allow all of the controls in the view to bind to the result of this operation, and share the resulting state.

The example below is a bit long, but it's the smallest sample that I could think of to demonstrate the pros and cons of this first approach.

```
internal class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
    private readonly int _personID;

    public ParentViewModel(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory, int personID)
    {  
        this._unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        this._personID = personID;
  
        _data = new NotifyTask<ParentViewModel_Context?>(LoadDataAsync(),null);
    }

    private NotifyTask<ParentViewModel_Context?> _data;
    public NotifyTask<ParentViewModel_Context?> Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => SetField(ref _data, value); //SetField is responsible for raising INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    private async Task<ParentViewModel_Context?> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        using var unitOfWork = await _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateAsync();

        var person = await unitOfWork.People.GetByIdAsync(_personID);
        List<Person> children = await unitOfWork.People.GetChildrenOfParentByParentIDAsync(_personID);

        var data = new ParentViewModel_Context()
        {
            InChargeOfDepartment = person.Department,
            PersonName = person.Name
        };

        var childrenVMs = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>(
                children.Select(c => new ChildViewModel()
                {
                    PersonName = c.Name,
                    HostVM = data
                }));

        data.Children = childrenVMs;

        return data;
    }
}

internal class ParentViewModel_Context : ViewModelBase
{

    private string? _inChargeOfDepartment;
    public string? InChargeOfDepartment
    {
        get => _inChargeOfDepartment;
        set => SetField(ref _inChargeOfDepartment, value);
    }

    private string? _personName;
    public string? PersonName
    {
        get => _personName;
        set => SetField(ref _personName, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>? _children;
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>? Children
    {
        get => _children;
        set => SetField(ref _children, value);
    }
}

internal class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IViewModel? _hostVM;
    public IViewModel? HostVM
    {
        get => _hostVM;
        set => SetField(ref _hostVM, value);
    }

    private string? _personName;
    public string? PersonName
    {
        get => _personName;
        set => SetField(ref _personName, value);
    }

}
```

The downsides that I can see are:

1. As you can see in the sample, I think this would require a second "ViewModel" `ParentViewModel_Context` to contain all of the bindable properties, to ensure that all values are returned to the UI thread through the single Task result. Normally, I would have all of the properties on `ParentViewModel_Context` reside directly on `ParentViewModel`.
2. All child ViewModels are being new-ed in `LoadDataAsync`, and all of their data is being pushed into them. This is a relatively small sample, but real-world examples with deep nested ViewModels will have massive `LoadDataAsync` methods. I also feel like this is something that DI or a `ViewModelFactory` might be a better approach for.
3. Thread-safety is still feeling like arcane knowledge to me, and I have no idea if this approach introduces possible threading issues.

There are some things that could be tweaked about this approach. I could treat `ParentViewModel_Context` as a simple DTO, have the bindable properties directly on the `ParentViewModel`, and load the bindable properties from the DTO after the task is complete.

This feels a little better, but this looks to require a way to have a continuation task to trigger after `LoadDataAsync()` returns, in order to transfer the data from the DTO to the properties. The only way that I can see to do this is `.ContinueWith()`, but my reading has cautioned me on using `.ContinueWith()` (though I will say the reasons did escape my understanding). I also think that `.ContinueWith()` runs on another thread, so I think I would have to use the `Dispatcher` to ensure I'm setting from the UI thread.

I have no idea if this is really any better than binding through the single `Data.Result` property. It would also change how you bind your data, and would likely involve a little more thought in how to represent state.

The second approach I could see is to have each property that involves an asynchronous loading operation to have it's own `NotifyTask`:

```
internal class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
    private readonly int _personID;

    public ParentViewModel(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory, int personID)
    {
        this._unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        this._personID = personID;

        _inChargeOfDepartment = new NotifyTask<string?>(LoadDepartmentAsync(), null);
        _personName = new NotifyTask<string?>(LoadNameAsync(), null);
        _children = new NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>?>(LoadChildrenAsync(), null);
        
    }

    private NotifyTask<string?> _inChargeOfDepartment;
    public NotifyTask<string?> InChargeOfDepartment
    {
        get => _inChargeOfDepartment;
        set => SetField(ref _inChargeOfDepartment, value);
    }

    private NotifyTask<string?> _personName;
    public NotifyTask<string?> PersonName
    {
        get => _personName;
        set => SetField(ref _personName, value);
    }

    public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>?> _children;
    public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>?> Children
    {
        get => _children;
        set => SetField(ref _children, value);
    }

    private async Task<string?> LoadNameAsync()
    {
        using var unitOfWork = await _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateAsync();

        var person = await unitOfWork.People.GetByIdAsync(_personID);

        return person.Name;
    }

    private async Task<string?> LoadDepartmentAsync()
    {
        using var unitOfWork = await _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateAsync();

        var person = await unitOfWork.People.GetByIdAsync(_personID);

        return person.Department;
    }

    private async Task<ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>> LoadChildrenAsync()
    {
        using var unitOfWork = await _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateAsync();

        List<Person> children = await unitOfWork.People.GetChildrenOfParentByParentID(_personID);        

        var childrenVMs = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>(
                children.Select(c => new ChildViewModel()
                {
                    PersonName = c.Name,
                    HostVM = this
                }));

        return childrenVMs;
    }
}
```

This already feels better. There is no longer one giant Load method, and each property receives it's own value directly via it's own dedicated `NotifyTask.Result`.

The two biggest drawbacks that I can see are:

1. There is no single state being reported. Each `NotifyTask` can fail or succeed independently. I can't see a simple way to consolidate the results of all of these separate tasks into one result for the UI to use to choose it's state.
2. This method can result in duplicate effort across multiple `Load...()` methods. This is demonstrated by both `LoadDepartmentAsync()` and `LoadNameAsync()` querying the database for the same person to access a single property.

Another outstanding issue is the fact that this solution is still new-ing instances of `ChildViewModel` and pushing data into it. I feel that this would become unmanageable very fast with deeply nested ViewModel hierarchies.

To resolve this, you could treat each nested ViewModel as being responsible for loading its own data, using the same pattern as in the second sample above. You could even create a factory pattern to abstract away the construction of these child ViewModels. The `ChildViewModel` class would then look like:

```
internal class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
    private readonly int _personID;

    public ChildViewModel(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory, int personID, IViewModel host)
    {        
        this._unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        this._personID = personID;
        this._hostVM = host;
        _personName = new NotifyTask<string?>(LoadNameAsync(), null);
    }

    private IViewModel? _hostVM;
    public IViewModel? HostVM
    {
        get => _hostVM;
        set => SetField(ref _hostVM, value);
    }

    private NotifyTask<string?> _personName;
    public NotifyTask<string?> PersonName
    {
        get => _personName;
        set => SetField(ref _personName, value);
    }

    private async Task<string?> LoadNameAsync()
    {
        using var unitOfWork = await _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateAsync();

        var person = await unitOfWork.People.GetByIdAsync(_personID);

        return person.Name;
    }
}
```

... and the `LoadChildrenAsync()` method might look like:

```
private async Task<ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>> LoadChildrenAsync()
{
    using var unitOfWork = await _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateAsync();

    List<Person> children = await unitOfWork.People.GetChildrenOfParentByParentID(_personID);

    var childrenVMs = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>(
            children.Select(c => _childViewModelFactory.Create(c.ID, this)));

    return childrenVMs;
}
```

This should resolve the issue of having to load the entire ViewModel tree and push data to every descendant. This also, however, exacerbates the issue of not having a single state to use in the view, as that is now spread across many properties on many ViewModels.

It also might make the duplicate effort issue more pronounced. Imagine if `ChildViewModel` had a `List<City> Cities` property to use as the `DataSource` of a ComboBox. If each `ChildViewModel` is responsible for fetching its own data, each child would be making their own trip to the database to retrieve the same city list.

This could be minimized if you created a proxy for caching immutable drop-down data sources, but that doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Is there a Goldilocks approach that I'm not seeing that handles all of the concerns I've encountered:

1. Asynchronously loads properties in a deeply nested hierarchy of ViewModels
2. Has a synchronized state that reports the aggregate results of the entire load functionality
3. Avoids massive `LoadDataAsync()` methods
4. Avoids many atomic and potentially duplicate trips to the database
5. works decently with the IoC pattern
6. Respects thread-safety

Lastly (though this is more of an aside), initializing and populating an `ObservableCollection` inside of a Task feels wrong. Should I be returning a basic list of items so that it can be passed to the `ObservableCollection` constructor on the UI thread? If so, how do I do this? `.ContinueWith()` + `Dispatcher`?

Comment: Wow, I feel overwhelmed by the content of your question. It's big and find my self asking what your original goal was. First of all, you should never call async methods from the constructor. The can't be awaited in this context. There exist different patterns to solve this problem. One is to hide the constructor (private) and expose a "factory method". This method can be async and is awaitable (because it is not a constructor or property). Or expose a public constructor but let the caller call an InitializeAsync method to execute the long running initialization.

Comment: Maybe this already solves your problem. The first approach returnes a completely initialized type (while the initialization won't block) while the second approach allows the caller to defer this expensive initialization (also non-blocking because async).

Comment: ContinueWith is a member of the old Task API before there was async/await. Today instead of ContinueWith we use await.

Comment: I don't think you need NotifyTask at all in your scenario.

Comment: Thrad-safety is only an issue if you access resources that are shared between multiple threads. You usually make a class thread-safe by introducing a locking mechanism (like `lock` or a kind of monitor) to synchronize access to the shared resources.

Comment: In MVVM the database acces usually takes place in the Model and not in the View Model. The View Model usually asks the Model for data without knowing where this data is coming from.

Comment: Usually you would read data from the Model and then store it in the properties of the View Model in order to expose the data to the View. You would use a trigger like a command routine to read/save new data. Except from initialization. usually the user triggers such operations. There is no need to return property values directly from the database (or data source in general). It's even a bad idea in terms of performance. You don't want every property read to result in an expensive data operation. You always cache when possible.

Comment: That's why NotifyTask rather introduces a code smell instead of helping you. You can also observe the data source for changes and let the view model update itself with fresh data if this is necessary.

Comment: If you design your data contexts (view model classes) properly, there is no need to have duplicate data sources for the UI. For example, only a single view model class should expose a List<City> Cities property. If other view models need to access this collection too, use composition to compose your classes.

Comment: Initializing and populating an ObservableCollection on a background thread  is fine. While PropertyChanged is always automatically marshaled to the UI thread (by the binding engine), CollectionChanged is not. It's your responsibility to marshal this event. I recommend to enable automatic marshaling by registering the ObservableCollection with the binding engine using the static [`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#remarks) method.

Comment: I would recommend returning a list to the UI and building a new observable collection when you're reading loads of data. I usually have a task which gets the data for a viewmodel and can be run after construction to get all it's data. Use dto from your model and copy to viewmodels. Automapper makes that easy and will copy list of dto to list of viewmodel efficiently with minimal coding.

Comment: I want to thank @BionicCode and Andy for their comments. I appreciate how much effort BionicCode took to respond to multiple parts of my question. There is a lot of good advice in their comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these are opposing forces:

> Avoids massive LoadDataAsync() methods
>
> Avoids many atomic and potentially duplicate trips to the database

If you can structure the data retrieval in a single operation (e.g., one complex db query, or a single call to a backend-for-frontend), then that's usually more efficient. It sounds like most of your queries are independent, though, except for some that are exact duplicates of others.

So, I imagine you'll probably end up with a kind of lazy-loading solution where each query will return its data if it's already been run. Note that this doesn't actually have anything to do with MVVM or ViewModels or even `async`: the problem is actually that you have a whole bunch of work to do (`LoadDataAsync`), but you can't break it up completely because you don't want to duplicate work that overlaps. Lazy evaluation is one solution to this problem: break it up but memoize the results. I.e., the "caching proxy" you suggested. I have an `AsyncLazy<T>` type in my AsyncEx library that may be useful for that.

Now, on to the VM/async concerns.

I prefer (and from your question it sounds like you do, too) to have each VM have its own asynchronous data loading - in this case, hitting the proxy so that it only does additional work necessary. It's a matter of preference whether each property should have its own loading UI state; if you have a decent Suspense/Spinner component, some people are fine with a bunch of spinners that complete at different times.

It sounds like you just want one overall "everything beneath me has loaded" spinner, though. Which is also totally a fine choice.

The key to that approach is the `NotifyTask<T>.Task` property. It provides a way to detect completion (and errors) using an actual `Task` instead of observable properties.

So, you can use `Task.WhenAll` to build a `Task` that completes when the scalar properties have completed loading; consider the child VM first:

```
var initializationTask = await Task.WhenAll(
    _personName.Task,
    ... /* any other properties */ );
```

You can then wrap that up into a single `NotifyTask` that represents the initialization of the child VM as a whole:

```
NotifyTask Initialization { get; }
...
Initialization = NotifyTask.Create(() => Task.WhenAll(
    _personName.Task,
    ... /* any other properties */ ));
```

Next, extend this same idea to the parent VM; the scalar properties are straightforward:

```
NotifyTask Initialization { get; }
...
Initialization = NotifyTask.Create(() => Task.WhenAll(
    _inChargeOfDepartment.Task,
    _personName.Task));
```

The child VMs are a little odder; you need to first `await` for them to exist in the collection, and then `await` the initialization of each one:

```
NotifyTask Initialization { get; }
...
Initialization = NotifyTask.Create(async () =>
{
  await Task.WhenAll(
      _inChargeOfDepartment.Task,
      _personName.Task,
      _children.Task);
  var children = await _children.Task;
  await Task.WhenAll(children.Select(x => x.Initialization.Task));
});
```

This then gives you an `Initialization` property on your parent VM that represents the initialization of all its own properties and all of its children (which represent the initialization of all their properties). Exceptions are propagated and available off the `ParentViewModel.Initialization` notification task as usual. Meanwhile, the async-lazy proxy ensures that there's no duplication of effort.

Side notes:

- While it's possible to set a `NotifyTask<T>` (and sometimes you want to), a lot of the time they can just be `get`-only properties.
- You are correct to hesitate to use `ContinueWith`. The modern replacement for `ContinueWith` is `await`.
- There's nothing wrong with creating/populating an `ObservableCollection` in an `async` method, as long as that code is running on the UI thread. If the `async` method is called from the UI thread and if it doesn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` anywhere, then the code will be running on the UI thread and there's no problem there.
- Avoid using the `Dispatcher` directly; I just mention this because you mentioned it at a couple points in your question. There's almost always a better solution than using `Dispatcher`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond so thoroughly! I was concerned that I was approaching the idea of initialization completely wrong, so I appreciate your insight. I actually do have my UI designed so that each control can report on its own state using attached behaviors with adorners, but I wasn't sure if I should wire that up to their own results or come collective result. Its good to hear either is fine. Thank you for showing me how to gather all of the task results into one property, that was extremely useful. I'm going to start applying this to my project! Thanks again!

Comment: I came across an odd usecase. I am trying to load a ComboBox's collection, and then set the SelectedItem to the first element in the collection. I made the SelectedItem a NotifyTask. In it, I awaited the Collection.Task, and then returned the first element of the Collection.Task.Result. This worked, but the binding of SelectedItem.Result requires a OneWay binding. Does this imply that NotifyTask should only be used for properties that aren't meant to be edited from the view? Should I bind to NotifyTask for state, then have a second property for TwoWay value binding?

Comment: ...and if you do need a second property to be able to use TwoWay Binding, how could you transfer the NotifyTask.Result to the TwoWay bindable property, after NotifyTask.Task completes? If you can't await it in the constructor, is there some other way to queue up a synchronous operation to fire after a task completes? This is starting to feel like it should be in a new question. I don't want to abuse the comments, so I'll create a new question and link to it in a comment that follows this one.

Comment: @Chronicide: I'm not sure if I entirely understand what you're asking, but NotifyTask isn't writable from the view. I tend to prefer one-way data flow anyway, more similar to most modern JS frameworks.

Comment: What if you need the user to update the value of a property that was originally initialized using NotifyTask? I've created a second question with more information about what I'm looking to achieve, as well as what I've considered for solutions. I already appreciate the answer you've provided here, so please do not feel obligated to answer my other question. If you do have the time, though, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75979466/async-wpf-mvvm-using-notifytask-asyncex-for-twoway-binding). Thank you again for the help you've provided so far!