# Async WPF MVVM: Using NotifyTask (AsyncEx) for TwoWay binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous, mvvm

I'm just getting started on understanding how to incorporate Asynchronous data loading in WPF applications. I've read [Stephen Cleary's article on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding), and I found it very helpful. It demonstrates how to initialize your view to a "loading" state, and to also have states to reflect a "faulted" state and a "completed loading" state. In brief, it introduces a class called `NotifyTaskCompletion` (now called `NotifyTask` in his AsyncEx library).

This class can be used to start a task in the constructor without awaiting it. The class exposes bindable properties to report the state and result of the task (`IsCompleted`, `IsFaulted`, `Result`, etc.). In this way, you can bind to NotifyTask.IsFaulted in a DataTrigger to change the style to visualize a fault state.

I really like this idea, and I've started using `NotifyTask` in my latest project. In doing this, I discovered that `NotifyTask.Result` is just a property that either returns a default value that you provide to show while loading, or the return value from the executed task.

As `NotifyTask.Result` doesn't have a setter that calls `PropertyChanged`, it can only be bound in WPF as `OneWay`. Upon taking another look at the article, the provided example only binds to `Label.Content`, which is inherently `OneWay`.

How can I use something like `NotifyTask` that also allows for the View to use `TwoWay` bindings? I can think of two ways, but, being new to asynchronous programming, I'm uncertain which approach makes more sense (or if there is a better way that I can't see).

**Approach 1**

Use `NotifyTask` for reporting on state, and don't bind to `NotifyTask.Result` directly. This would mean having a second property to bind to. For example:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LoadTextTask.IsNotCompleted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

C#

```
internal class Example_Method1 : ViewModelBase
{
    internal Example_Method1()
    {
        LoadTextTask = new NotifyTask<string?>(LoadText(), null);
    }

    public NotifyTask<string?> LoadTextTask {get; private set;}

    private string? _text;
    internal string? Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => SetField(ref _text, value); // SetField is responsible for calling PropertyChanged
    }

    private async Task<string?> LoadText()
    {
        return await DAL.ReallyHeavyLoadingOperation();
    }
}
```

One piece that I'm missing is how I can transfer the result of `LoadTextTask` to `Text`. I can't `await` in a constructor, which is the whole point of having `NotifyTask`. I could maybe create an event handler in the `NotifyTask` class that fires when the internal task is completed, subscribe to the event in Example_Method1, and transfer the result from `LoadTextTask` to `Text` when it does fire.

This means having two properties and an event handler wired up for each property I need to load asynchronously, which feels a little over architected. To minimize this, I could follow this same pattern, but use one `NotifyTask` to load all of the data asynchronously, then transfer all of the loaded data to the appropriate bindable properties in the ViewModel. This does require a DTO or tuple to return multiple values from the task... and I still don't know how to trigger the transfer of data from the task to the ViewModel properties upon task completion, as I can't await in a constructor.

**Approach 2**

Create a generic class with a single `Value` property that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then use this generic class to wrap the return type for `NotifyTask`

C#:

```
internal class Notifiable<TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Notifiable(TResult? value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private TResult? _value;
    internal TResult? Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<TResult>.Default.Equals(_value, value))
            {
                _value = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}

internal class Example_Method2 : ViewModelBase
{
    internal Example_Method2()
    {
        Text = new NotifyTask<Notifiable<string?>>(LoadText(), null);
    }

    internal NotifyTask<Notifiable<string?>> Text {get; private set; }

    private async Task<Notifiable<Notifiable<string?>>> LoadText()
    {
        return new Notifiable(await DAL.ReallyHeavyLoadingOperation());
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text.Result.Value}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.IsNotCompleted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

This allows `TwoWay` binding, and combines the functions of the `Text` and `LoadTextTask` properties from the first approach into one property. Unlike the first method, I was able to get this method to work. That said, like method 1, it also feels a little over architected. Also, this method puts the bound setter into another class (`Notifiable.Value._set`), so you can't customize the setter logic per property (for example, to enforce uppercase on a particular property by using `_value = value.ToUpper` in the setter).

I think I could incorporate the function of `Notifiable<TResult>` into `NotifyTask<TResult>` to expose a bindable property that wraps `NotifyTask.Result`, but as `NotifyTask.Result` currently only has a calculated getter, this presents a little more complexity for implementation.

I am really hoping that I'm overlooking a third option here, and I would appreciate any insight into how to use `NotifyTask` with `TwoWay` bindings.

Comment: I really think you are little bit too much over it. The NotifyTask that you describe is only useful in very specific scenarios. It is not meant to replace the common binding pattern or infrastructure. I wonder what scenario you are about to use this, because i don't believe it's worth the overhead you are about to introduce just to make it work. Using NotifyTask already makes your code less intuitive and kind of awkward. You are just about to exaggerate on that. Why don't you use normal property binding?

Comment: Here are my 2ct on a clean and more intuitive implementation. Trigger the long running operation via a simple method call, event or command. If this long running operation is about data, then this should be handled in the application model. For example, the model would load data on a background thread during startup and then notify the view model once the data is ready via an event. You should check your design if you found yourself in the need to implement async constructors or properties.

Comment: Trying hard to make it work e.g. by using some workarounds like NotifyTask is not the best decision in terms of class design. You don't fix a code smell by wrapping it into something fancy. You must fix your design. Longrunning constructors or properties make a class expensive. This costs are hidden from the caller as nobody expects a constructor or property to take time to return or to allocate expensive resources.

Comment: You should always try to allocate resources or generate data when it is needed. This way you can give the client of your class the chance to use a lightweight class in case the expensive operation is not even needed. Did you realize that NotifyTask can only be used once? To set it you need to create a new instance (it's immutable). It's not designed for two way binding. Anything else is opinion based. I think you should not create all this overhead and code smell in disguise and let go the NotifyTask in your particular case. Better improve your design.

Comment: In the end this remains a highly subjective topic. But to me your code does not appear to be aesthetically appealing in any way. Especially when thinking about why you are doing all this. I mean all I see is the code smell.

Comment: Also having a partially loaded GUI is just a bad idea in terms of UX. From the user perspective you just present him some randomly disabled text boxes. The user doesn't know why and when/if they become accessible. There is always the more graceful solution of presenting the user a splash screen. This way you communicate to the user that the application is still responsive while being initialized. User don't love splash screens but they kind of expect them. If they don't display for minutes they are fine.

Comment: In addition you can partition initialization like only loading the most important data and continue in the background while the user can start to work. Just pay attention how Visual Studio is starting. It starts quite fast: it briefly shows a little splash screen and then you can already start your work while there is still a lot of initialization running in the background. No randomly disabled text boxes or buttons.